# Number Type from Oracle to Teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, teradata, precision

I need to replicate some tables of Oracle in Teradata.
I have a script that create the sql for the Teradata's table, so far everything worked fine but I have a small problem.

I look the information for the columns type in the table "all_tab_columns", but I have find that some NUMBER columns have data_precision and data_scale as NULL. So I can't replicate them in Teradata because the NUMBER type demands precision and scale, both greater than 0.

Has anyone worked with this or can give me an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `number` or `number(*)` in Teradata, too.
Simply try it.

Comment: . . I hadn't realized that the maximum precision for numbers in both Teradata and Oracle is 38.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Teradata's NUMBER mimics Oracle's NUMBER, there were too many projects porting from Oracle :-)

Comment: @dnoeth But in this way, using NUMBER(*) in teradata, if I have a column of type NUMBER with information of Years, for example, in Oracle I have 2010 and in Teradata I would have 2010.00.
And it's not the same...

Comment: @dnoeth . . . I wish BigQuery had the same attitude ;)  That is where I faced this problem . . . and had to bring columns in as strings rather than numbers.

Comment: @mozas: `2010.00` vs. `2010` is just a display issue, i.e. a client setting, Teradata would show the latter when casted to a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: At least BigQuery got a limited kind of NUMERIC in beta...

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Is it still in beta?  I thought it was released.

Comment: OK @dnoeth , your arguments convince me ;)